# In python3, is there a good way to match words beginning or ending with the character × (multiplication sign, not an x)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for patterns such as '×55' or '55×', which can appear anywhere in the string including the start or end.  × is not a word character, so \b will not match the typical non-word/word delimiters.  I'm finding myself building my own delimiter set '(^|\s|,|.)×\d+' and figure there has got to be a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with `\d×|x\d` ?

Comment: Try a non word boundary, `\B×\d+\b|\b\d+×\B`

Comment: @Bohemian - that would match more than words beginning or ending with × (e.g. Do not match th4×is or th×8×is)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did it, thanks.  Took some thinking to get my head around using a non-word boundary as a word boundary, but I get it.  If you submit it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match a nonword char not preceded/followed with a word char, you may  use a non word boundary `\B` before/after this nonword char:

```
 \B×\d+\b|\b\d+×\B
```

Comment: I will add a demo and full explanation when I get back home.